# Android: callback for search widget opened and dismissed

Tags: android, search, callback, widget, screen-orientation

I have a screen layout that is forced to be `potrait mode`. Because it is very complex I don't have the time right now to invest creating a separate one for `landscape mode`. It also doesn't make much sense for my type of application.

However, for input fields it's better to provide a `landscape mode`, because some phones have a hardware keyboard, which automatically aligns the phone in landscape and therefor makes it hard to look at the app that is still in `portrait mode`.

My solution to this is to put all text input into a dialog and temporarily enable landscape mode (if requested by the user) until the dialog is dismissed again.

This works perfectly. Except of the overlaying search widget (when pressing the search button from my application). I'm looking for two *callbacks*: one, when the search widget is raised (I cannot listen to the search button, because I sometimes raise it manually via a soft button) and when it is dismissed again (regardless if the search was finally triggered or canceled - it needs to work for both cases).

Any suggestions?

Comment: was there another answer on this question that was deleted? (@CommonsWare ??)

Answer (score 3):

There is an `Activity` callback for when search is activated. [`onSearchRequested()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSearchRequested%28%29)

For the dismiss/cancel of the search widget, you can add listeners via the `SearchManager`:

- [`SearchManager.OnCancelListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SearchManager.OnCancelListener.html)
- [`SearchManager.OnDismissListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SearchManager.OnDismissListener.html)

Get a reference to your `SearchManager` with:

```
context.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE)
```

see [`getSystemService()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

When using the Search Widget you can use the OnActionExpandListener on the associated action bars menu item. This also works great with the AppCompat Support Library for API versions below 14.

The [OnActionExpandListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener.html) has two methods:

- onMenuItemActionCollapse
- onMenuItemActionExpand

See some code example below:

```
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            KLog.i(TAG, "onMenuItemActionCollapse");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            KLog.i(TAG, "onMenuItemActionExpand");
            return true;
        }

    });

    mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

    mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

In case you do not use the Support Library use the OnActionExpandListener on the menu item directly.